# Перезагрузка компонента Angular 2

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

Такой вопрос, как при нажатии кнопки в одном компоненте перезагрузить другой компонент, знаю про метод reset, но как его применить к моему не знаю(использовал лишь для перезагрузки того же элемента , в котором и кнопка
Нужно при нажатии кнопки тут https://github.com/KorobkaVadim/Family-Tree/blob/master/app/app-item/app-item.component.html
перезагрузить этот https://github.com/KorobkaVadim/Family-Tree/blob/master/app/app-list/app-list.component.html

Comment: или как организовать через eventemmiter

Comment: Ещё [mcve] в сам вопрос добавь.